# Is it good idea to store store List<100000> Pojo objects in memory

Tags: java

for some test data scenario i need to read file containing 100000 lines of row and process each row with some condition and then based on condition need to output the data in text format

for this i am planning to store all lines of data in some pojo then pojo to List
My worry is to having pojo of 100000 row in memory . this is just for testing case .

Comment: **It depends.** Sorry, but with this amount of information, it is not possible to give a better answer... Please condsider adding: what kind of information is in the POJOs, how large are they? Do they fit in the heap? (also, I'd be tempted to say that for testing anything goes, but that depends too...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you should go through `generics` first.

Comment: You should first do it and then ask about any specific problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using InputSteam to read the file will be better since you still fetch rows one by one. You can read one line per time, and process your confition and then output.

Storing too much Objects in List may encounter an Out of Memory Error.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, its a bad design to store all 100000 rows as POJO in memory. Some of the possible solutions are:

1. Read one row at a time and process it.
2. Rather than reading from a file one record at a time and processing it using java, use some scripting language to populate a database table, and then from your java code you can process the records from the table.